# SignTool Error: The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or returned an invalid response

Tags: signtool

I am using "Global Sign" USB token to sign my product DLL's but getting the below error message :

**Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or
returned an invalid response.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign**

The command I'm using for signing the Dll's has been given below :

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool>signtool.exe sign /n "XXX SOFTWARE TECHNOLOGIES LIMITED" /fd SHA256 /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/advanced /td SHA256 "XXX\bin\x64\Release\OutlookAddIn.dll"*

My dll does not get signed and shown the above error.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Below are my environment details :

Windows 10

Visual studio 2019 pro

.Net framework 4.8

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to server inaccessibility by the certificate vendor or from the source machine. Check from the machine  where timestamp URL http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/advanced is not restricted, otherwise you must discuss with vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If the timestamp server isn't available you can try another one from this list:

https://gist.github.com/Manouchehri/fd754e402d98430243455713efada710